# Trouble Pulling HTML attribute

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and am having trouble scraping some HTML code.

I am trying to pull the text "Coupon", "Maturity Date", and "Initial Offering Price" as well as the text in the `float-right` class from the HTML code below. I only included part of the HTML code but there are nine different sections that I am trying to scrape from

```
<span class="label genericQtipHelp" help="Annual interest rate payable on a security expressed as a percentage of the principal" data-hasqtip="160" aria-describedby="qtip-160">Coupon:</span>
<span class="float-right">3 %</span>
<span class="label genericQtipHelp" help="Date the principal becomes due and payable to bondholders" data-hasqtip="161">Maturity Date:</span>
<span class="float-right">08/12/2021</span>
<span class="label genericQtipHelp" help="Price / Yield at which a new issue of municipal securities is offered to the public" data-hasqtip="163">Initial Offering Price/Yield:</span>
<span class="float-right">3 %</span>
```

I was able to pull the date from the second line (class `float-right`) of HTML using the following code:

**Input**

```
elements2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("float-right")
for data2 in elements2:
    print(data2.text)
```

**Output**

```
3 %
08/01/2022
08/12/2021
102.829% / 0.08%
$4,525,000
07/30/2021 09:14 AM
07/30/2021 01:30 PM
08/12/2021
-
```

This returns all of the data stored in the `float-right` class and is exactly what I need. However when I try pulling "Maturity Date" and the other data from the first line of HTML I run into errors. I believe this is because I am trying to get an attribute?

The code is used to try and pull Maturity Date and the other text is as follows:

**Input 1**

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("label genericQtipHelp").__getattribute__('data-hasqtip')
for data in elements:
   print(data.text)
```

**Output 1**

```
 elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("label genericQtipHelp").__getattribute__('data-hasqtip')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data-hasqtip'
```

**Input 2**

```
elements = soup.find('class', attrs={"label genericQtipHelp":'data-hasqtip'})
print(elements.text)
```

**Output 2**

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I have tried a couple of other things but I am ending up with similar errors. How do I pull this data and is there a simpler way to pull *Maturity Date* and *3%* for all nine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use Selenium for **parsing** HTML. It's extremely SLOW in that (10+ times slower on large pages (1M+ size) than `lxml`. I recommend to use `lxml` (or Beautiful Soup):

```
from lxml import html

.....
content = driver.page_source
tree = html.fromstring(content)

data = {}
for float_right_node in tree.xpath('//span[@class="float-right"]'):
    value = float_right_node.xpath('string(./text())')
    key = float_right_node.xpath('string(./preceding-sibling::span[1]/text())')
    data[key] = value
    print(f"{key:35} {value}")
```

Comment: Thank you @gangabass! This worked, I have one last question though. Is there a way to format the output into a list, like the one I would get using Ram's answer, rather than just one single line? I used 'for details in data: print(details)' and that worked to return all of the title names (Coupon, Maturity Date..) but not the values (3%, 08/12/2021). associated with it.

Comment: thank you, can you explain what the 35 in `{key:35}` is?

Comment: @user16768885 `key` is a variable name and `:35` is a width for this field in output.

Answer (score 0):

`label genericQtipHelp` is actually 2 separate class names: `label` and `genericQtipHelp` while `find_elements_by_class_name` method is supposed to get a single class name. In case of multiple class names you have to use XPath or css selector.
Additionally `label genericQtipHelp` class attribute value is not unique, it matches both `Annual interest rate` and `Date the principal` and `Price / Yield` elements.
So, to uniquely match the `Annual interest rate` elements you can use

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@help,'Annual interest rate')]").__getattribute__('data-hasqtip')
for data in elements:
    print(data)
```

You do not need to apply `.text` on `data` since it is already a string, no a web element.
Similarly to the above, to see the `Date the principal` elements `data-hasqtip` values you can use

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@help,'Date the principal')]").__getattribute__('data-hasqtip')
for data in elements:
    print(data)
```

The same with the third element containing `Price / Yield` in `help` attribute.

Comment: Hi @Prophet, thank you for taking the time to help answer my question! I tried implementing the code above however I still received the AttributeError. I am trying to get "Coupon" out of the following HTML code: `aria-describedby="qtip-160">Coupon:</span`. I am looking into multiple class names so thank you for showing that. In the HTML code in my original post you will see that there is Coupon, Maturity Date, and Initial Offering Price/Yield. This is the data I am trying grab. They all share a common class attribute, data-hasqtip..I think.. is there a way to pull the text linked to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using `beautifulsoup`.

- Find all the `<span>` with class name as `label genericQtipHelp` using `.find_all()` method. *This will give you a list of all the `<span>` with given class name.* It's text is the name [Maturity, Coupon , Yield etc.,]
- Iterate over the above list and for every span, find the next span (*the value is present inside this span.*) using `findNext('span')` and get it's value.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<span class="label genericQtipHelp" help="Annual interest rate payable on a security expressed as a percentage of the principal" data-hasqtip="160" aria-describedby="qtip-160">Coupon:</span>
<span class="float-right">3 %</span>
<span class="label genericQtipHelp" help="Date the principal becomes due and payable to bondholders" data-hasqtip="161">Maturity Date:</span>
<span class="float-right">08/12/2021</span>
<span class="label genericQtipHelp" help="Price / Yield at which a new issue of municipal securities is offered to the public" data-hasqtip="163">Initial Offering Price/Yield:</span>
<span class="float-right">3 %</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
spans = soup.find_all('span', class_='label genericQtipHelp')


for span in spans:
    name = span.text.strip()
    val = span.findNext('span').text.strip()
    print(f"{name:35} {val}")
```

```
Coupon:                             3 %
Maturity Date:                      08/12/2021
Initial Offering Price/Yield:       3 %
```